# in ReactJS How to enable mui snackbar only when login is success?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

in ReactJS I want to show material-ui snackbar only when login is success.
what are the ways to do this in ReactJS?

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Comment: Yes I am using redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple if you are using redux in react
open property is false by default you should true it in your reducer of LOG_IN_SUCCESS then snack bar will be showed after successfull login.

Answer (score 2):

Material-ui Snackbar takes a state true or false for its `open` state and hence its relatively easy to show it when the login is a success.

Considering that you are using Redux to store the login state

You can do it like

```
<Snackbar
      open={this.props.loggedIn}
      message="Event added to your calendar"
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
    />
```

In case you are not using Redux and storing the login status in a cookie,

You can load it to a state

```
componentDidMount() {
    var loggedIn = cookie.load('isLoggedIn');
    this.setState({loggedIn});
}

<Snackbar
      open={this.state.loggedIn}
      message="Event added to your calendar"
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
    />
```